# python selenium set default downloads directory with timestamp for windows

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

As captioned, anybody can help me to solve the problem? Many thanks!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

today = datetime.now()

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\XXX\Downloads\ + today.strftime("%Y%m%d")",
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

I would like to show the result like this:

"C:\Users\XXX\Downloads\20210301"

Answer (score 1):

```
  "download.default_directory": r"C:/Users/XXX/Downloads/" + today.strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

you had an issue in double quote here. Also you should change the lashes

Comment: I have followed your suggestion to run, but the result is occurs download failed.

Comment: And I used this script "download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\chungj\Downloads\20210301" to run, it is work fine. I don't know how to implement on it.

Comment: The error have shown "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal" if use the script of "download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\chungj\Downloads\" + today.strftime("%Y%m%d"). Thanks.